# feathers-mongodb Service.find({query: {_id}}) returns null

Tags: mongodb, graphql, feathersjs

I have the schemas below:

**students.graphql.schema.js**

```
export default [
  `
  type StudentsWithPagination {
    total: Int
    items: [Students]
  }

  type Students {
    _id: String!
    name: String
    address: Addresses
  }
`,
];
```

**addresses.graphql.schema.js**

```
export default [
      `
  type AddressesWithPagination {
    total: Int
    items: [Addresses]
  }

  type Addresses {
    _id: String!
    title: String
  }
`,
];
```

I have created two services by running `feathers generate service` **students.service.js** and **addresses.services.js**.

When I search addresses by `title`, I get result. However, when I search by `_id`, I get null. Something like:

```
const studentsResolvers = {
    Students: {
        address: student => {
            const query = {
                _id: student.address
            }
            return Addresses.find({ query }).then(result => {
                console.log(result)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The code above produces `null` though `student.address` returns the right `address._id`. I still get `null` even I hardcode `student.address` with the right `address._id`

The code above will return `null` unless I search by address title. Something like:

```
const query = {
   title: 'my-location'
}
```

`_id` is of type `String`, not `ObjectID`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _id is stored in the DB as objectId or string?

Comment: _id is stored in the DB as string not objectid

Comment: what's the result when u use `findById`?

Comment: I get `findById` is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documented in the feathers-mongodb adapter](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-mongodb#querying), since MongoDB itself (unlike Mongoose) does not have a schema, all query parameters have to be converted to the type in the database [in a hook](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html) manually. The example can be adapted accordingly for `$in` queries:

const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

```
app.service('users').hooks({
  before: {
    find(context) {
      const { query = {} } = context.params;

      if(query._id) {
        query._id  = new ObjectID(query._id);
      }

      if(query.age !== undefined) {
        query.age = parseInt(query.age, 10);
      }

      context.params.query = query;

      return Promise.resolve(context);
    }
  }
});
```